# How to Localize DATA

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, localization

For example I have a collection of departments

```
ObservableCollection<Department> Departments ...
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDepartmentId}"   
          SelectedValuePath="Id" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

As you can see the DisplayMemberPath is set to "Name", the name is in english.

Since this is **DATA** and **NOT UI** I don't think I should use resx resources because if a new department and it's translation is added, then it would need to recompile and release if resx where used.

How can I localize data?

Comment: If the department name is inputted by the user, I wouldn't expect that it would be your responsibility to translate it.

Comment: The user doesn't add the department, only a few administrators, perhaps only using a direct insert in SQL

Comment: Again, I still don't think this is your responsibility. How are you planning to cater for every possible department name? And how would you translate them? Also, how would you even know that you need to translate it? i.e How would you know that the department name is in English? I think I need to sit down.

Comment: The Departments don't change too often, and they all must in English, however a Hungarian person should see them translated in the combobox, at this point, I don't want to use resx to avoid a release in case a department is changed or renamed, perhaps the question is too broad and needs more clarification.

Comment: @MikeEason Thanks for the comments, I came up with something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is **MY** approach:

Have a table in the database with the localized values

```
Table Departments_Localized_Names
IdDepartment  ->  Foreign key to the original department
culture       ->  Relate to the culture/language 
LocalizedDisplayName ->  Translated department name
```

Using a partial entity class or even better a data transfer object, add the "LocalizedDisplayName" property, this property will be set only when the program loads, and the value will depend on the current culture

```
public partial class Department 
{
   //Set it at runtime according to the current culture
   public string LocalizedDisplayName{get;set;} 
}
```

So at the moment of displaying data, I pull the LocalizedDisplayName value from Departments_Localized_Names depending on the application current culture and the department id and set the LocalizedDisplayName on the object, that way I can just do the following:

```
      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}" 
      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDepartmentId}"   
      SelectedValuePath="Id" 
      DisplayMemberPath="LocalizedDisplayName" />
```

When inserting the new department, I just need to make sure the translated values are added to Departments_Localized_Names, and it should work without the need of a new release.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use a custom mark-up extension, [there's a good article about it here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/localizemarkupextension.html). I also give it a [custom namespace](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and) which allows me to write XAML like this:

```
<Label Content="{Translate 'First Name:'}" />
```

In addition to this I've written two utilities. The first searches all my XAML files for occurrences of the "{Translate ...}" mark-up and it saves the keys (e.g. 'First Name:') in a CSV file which can then be imported into a spreadsheet for the translators or pasted into Google translate etc for testing. The second utility then takes the values from the spreadsheet and turns them into XML which then gets loaded into the appropriate dictionary for my localization manager. The English dictionary is left empty, whenever a string isn't found in a dictionary it falls back to the key itself. This system means I can use English when writing my XAML but the process of exporting and importing the keys is completely automated and I can change language of all strings in my applications instantaneously at runtime.